# Error: invalid types ‘int [200][float]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, integer, sfml

I basically have a coordinates system and I  want to access the array by index of coordinates. `pos` is `Vector2f` (I use sfml).

```
            int iposy=static_cast<int>(pos.y);
            int iposx=static_cast<int>(pos.x);
            if(col[iposy][iposx]==N)
                col[iposy][iposx]=i;
            else{
             int vx1 = vx[i];
             int vx2 = vx[(col[iposy][iposx])];
             int vy1 = vy[i];
             int vy2 =vy[(col[iposy][iposx])];
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: invalid types ‘int [200][float]’ for array subscript
      int vx2 = vx[(col[iposy][iposx])];

error: invalid types ‘int [200][float]’ for array subscript
      int vy2 =vy[(col[iposy][iposx])];
```

Comment: Good idea to post the declaration of col, vx, vy, too...

Comment: @Aconcagua  int col[HEIGHT+1][WIDTH+1];
 for (int i=1;i<=HEIGHT;i++)
  for(int j=1;j<=WIDTH;j++)
   col[i][j]=N;

Comment: vx, vy? By the way: you did not initialize first row and first column of col, leaving it at 0 (if global or class variables) or uninitialized (if on stack). Is this intended?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes that was intended.

Comment: @Aconcagua oh vx and vy were integer arrays.col was declared as a float in my code.Thanks for guidance and sorry for misleading comment (col was float in my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the comments: if col is `float col[H][W];`, your trying to index vx/vy via a float. You would have to cast to int again:

```cpp
int vx2 = vx[static_cast<int>(col[iposy][iposx])];
int vy2 = vy[static_cast<int>(col[iposy][iposx])];
```

Be careful: There is no implicit index checking, so if your floats are out of range (negative or > WIDTH/HEIGHT), you most probably run into a segmentation fault...